# Searching a DICOM server for metadata

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

I want to search the DICOM  server. if for example user enters a patient id to serach, then my app populate a table with all the metadata relating to that id , such as id, name, accession number e.tc. if tha study id exists in the dicom server, How can this be done using dcm4chee kit. –

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **dcm4che3** tool `dcm4che-tool-findscu`. This code shows you how to do a C-FIND against a PACS (or whatever implementing C-FIND as SCP).

`FindSCU.java` is quite clear, take a while and don't get missed through Apache Commons CLI code to understand input from console. Most of CLI management code is not in this project, but you can find it in the **dcm4che3** tool `dcm4che-tool-common` project, `org.dcm4che3.tool.common.CLIUtils.java` class.

Take into account following considerations:

- Specify the search **level** of Query/Retrieve. You can use several search levels in order to match attributes into a PACS. If you look at lines 260:265 of `FindSCU.java`, you will see that you can manage four different levels: `PATIENT|STUDY|SERIES|IMAGE`.This will instruct C-FIND SCP how to search matching attributes.
- Tell C-FIND SCP what attributes do you want to retrieve. If you want to search studies to be retrieved later, you must ask for `0020, 000D` **Study​InstanceUID** tag.

  - Of course, add all attributes that you want to populate your table.
- Use retrieved `0020, 000D` **Study​InstanceUID** tag value to do the C-GET/C-MOVE operation.

You can see how to configure attribute keys to do C-FIND SCU into `CLIUtils.java` class that is part of **dcm4che3** tool `dcm4che-tool-common` project. See `CLIUtils.addAttributes(Attributes, String[])`.

Hope it helps!

### Edit

Due to you comment you are using dcm4che2 and that you already have a `DicomObject` with the search result, if you want to obtain metadata from this `DicomObject` you must parse it before, using `DicomInputStream`, and then you can use `getXXXX(Tag)` from `BasiDicomObject`, something like this:

```
DicomObject dcmObj;
DicomInputStream dis = null;
dis = new DicomInputStream(file);
dcmObj = dis.readDicomObject();
String someVar = dcmObj.getString(Tag.SeriesInstanceUID);
```

Keep in mind, some attributes are inside sequences, and thus you have to search it before.

You can also take a look into `dcm4che-tool-dcm2txt`, you will see `Dcm2Txt.java` and in lines 170 and so on, there is how to parse whole dicom object.

Comment: I have configured dcm4chee 2.028 , I have to configure dcm4che3 as well ??/

Comment: Well, I didn't know which version of dcm4chee were you using. If you are using dcm4che2, you can do almost the same, but using **dcm4che-tool-dcmqr**. Anyway, I recommend you to switch towards dcm4che3.

Comment: The result obtained is in the form of dicomobject how can I get the metadata in string form.

Answer (score 0):

If you need some general description about the DICOM network protocol, you could read the "[Understanding DICOM with Orthanc](https://orthanc.chu.ulg.ac.be/book/dicom-guide.html)" guide, and more specifically the [section about C-Find](https://orthanc.chu.ulg.ac.be/book/dicom-guide.html#c-find-browsing-the-content-of-a-server).